# Are questions about the health care system on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, allowed-questions

I was about to ask a question like

> What are the benefits of seeing a trans-specific primary care doctor?

when I realized that all the questions on here are about health, not about health care professionals or the health care system. Another similar question might be

> Should I ask questions about possible drug interactions to my doctor or pharmacist?

These might be poor examples, but hopefully the idea is clear. Are such questions on-topic here?

Answer (score 9):

I haven't read through all of the meta questions to know if this has been discussed before, but as a health-care professional, I believe sharing information on how best to interact with the health-care system would be very much on topic.

Who wouldn't like the inside scoop on which doctors are capable of handling problem X and for which do you need a specialist? Or, if you can't afford a patient-advocate to accompany you to your father's visit to the oncologist, what's the next best thing?

Yes, opinions are opinions, but isn't the point of this site to get a professional's perspective?

Answer (score 1):

From the examples you give, it does not seem like these types of questions would be on-topic, but I think there is a chance that they could be on-topic if worded right.

For your examples:

> What are the benefits of seeing a trans-specific primary care doctor?

Seems like this one would be opinionated and probably a little too broad.

> Should I ask questions about possible drug interactions to my doctor or pharmacist?

This one would also probably be closed as opinionated. It might also be too personal.

I have seen a question that I do think is on-topic that has to deal with the healthcare system though.

> [Should I go to the occupational therapist or the physical therapist if I have a tendinopathy in the USA?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/35/should-i-go-to-the-occupational-therapist-or-the-physical-therapist-if-i-have-a/36#36)

I think question like this would be on-topic. Other similar questions could also be on-topic, such as

> Which doctor should I go to if I have {x}?

Some of these questions would be opinionated, but if they are worded correctly, I think they would be on-topic.