# Are questions about med school on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There is a question in Academia about the ranking of med schools: [Does it matter where you go to medical school?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/35329/14341).

Does this question on-topic? We agree that question about health care system are on-topic*, but I'm not sure that this question will.

I would say no, since it is entirely have no relating to curing people. In my opinion, it's on-topic on Academia, but the community there decides that it's off-topic there.

<sub>*[Are questions about the health care system on-topic?](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/99/99)</sub>