# Is "which doctor to go see" a personal medical advice?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask a question about which doctor to go see given that my family doctor is now clueless about it (second and third advices are also clueless). Is it on topic?

Answer (score 8):

No, I don't think it is on topic. If you're asking for guidance about a particular physician or group, in addition to being a personal advice question, it's essentially a recommendation request and therefore likely to be opinion-based and a poor fit for the SE format.

On the other hand, if, by "which doctor" you mean which *type* of doctor (i.e. which sub-specialty), this might be more of a [healthcare systems question](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/99/165) that could be on topic. It would need to be carefully phrased to avoid being "opinion-based". It's possible to demonstrate objectively that a particular subspecialty routinely deals with a particular condition or set of symptoms, for instance, and this may be informative for your question.

Comment: Of course, I meant a specialist as a role. I never meant asking for names (doctor, hospital, etc.) Thanks! I'm pretty sure given my country and the number of people here on StackExchange, I'd get no info if I ever asked for a doctor by name ;)

Comment: There is at least one of those questions already on the site (what type of doctor to see to get screened for ovarian cancer)

Comment: There is also one here: [Should I go to the occupational therapist or the physical therapist if I have a tendinopathy in the USA?](http://health.stackexchange.com/q/35/26) They do require some details, but they do seem answerable and on-topic.